# Practical free monads for system-tests DSL: concurrency and error handling

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, free-monad, scala-cats

I'm trying to write a DSL for writing system tests in Scala. In this DSL I don't want to expose the fact that some operations might take place asynchronously (because they are implemented using the web-service under test for instance), or that errors might occur (because the web-service might not be available, and we want the test to fail). [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496349/2289983) this approach is discouraged, but I don't completely agree with this in the context of a DSL for writing tests. I think the DSL will get unnecessary polluted by the introduction of these aspects.

To frame the question, consider the following DSL:

```
type Elem = String

sealed trait TestF[A]
// Put an element into the bag.
case class Put[A](e: Elem, next: A) extends TestF[A]
// Count the number of elements equal to "e" in the bag.
case class Count[A](e: Elem, withCount: Int => A) extends TestF[A]

def put(e: Elem): Free[TestF, Unit] =
  Free.liftF(Put(e, ()))

def count(e: Elem): Free[TestF, Int] =
  Free.liftF(Count(e, identity))

def test0 = for {
  _ <- put("Apple")
  _ <- put("Orange")
  _ <- put("Pinneaple")
  nApples <- count("Apple")
  nPears <- count("Pear")
  nBananas <- count("Banana")
} yield List(("Apple", nApples), ("Pears", nPears), ("Bananas", nBananas))
```

Now assume we want to implement an interpreter that makes use of our service under test to put and count the elements in the store. Since we make use of the network, I'd like that the `put` operations take place asynchronously. In addition, given that network errors or server errors can occur, I'd like the program to stop as soon as an error occurs. To give an idea of what I want to achieve, [here](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/blob/master/free-monads/src/TestDSLExceptions.hs) is an example of mixing the different aspects in Haskell by means of monad transformers (that I cannot translate to Scala).

So my question is, which monad `M` would you use for an interpreter that satisfies the requirements above:

```
def interp[A](cmd: TestF[A]): M[A]
```

And in case M is a monad tranformer, how would you compose them using the FP library of your choice (Cats, Scalaz).

Comment: `Task` (scalaz or better fs2) should satisfy all of the requirements, it doesn't need monad-transformer as it's already has Either inside (Either for fs2, \/ for scalaz). It also has fast-fail behaviour you need, same as right-biased disjunction/xor.

Comment: I didn't know about `Task`, nice. This approach also seems to hint to how people compose monads in the scala world, forget about the `lift` operators from Haskell, define your own classes with all aspects you need mixed in (concurrency and error handling for instance), and define a monad instance for it.

Comment: You still kinda need lifting when using `Task`, lifting from value to `Task` or from `Either` to `Task`. But yes, it does seem to be simpler than monad transformers especially in respect to the fact monads are hardly composable (in order to define monad transformer you have to know some other details about your type besides being a monad - usually it requires something like comonad to extract value). Just for advertising purposes, I would also add that `Task` represents stack-safe trampolined computation. However there is some projects focused on monadic composition, like `Emm-monad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task` (scalaz or better fs2) should satisfy all of the requirements, it doesn't need monad-transformer as it's already has `Either` inside (`Either` for fs2, `\/` for scalaz). It also has a fast-fail behavior you need, same as right-biased disjunction/xor.

Here are several implementations that are known to me:

- Scalaz Task (original): [little outdated doc](http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/) and [new sources](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Task.scala)
- FS2 Task: https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/0.9/docs/guide.md It also provides interoperability (type classes) with `scalaz` and `cats`
- Monix Task: https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html
- "Cats" doesn't provide any `Task` or other `IO`-monad-related operations (no `scalaz-effect` analog at all) and recommends to use either Monix or FS2.

Regardless of monad-transformer absence, you still kinda need lifting when using `Task`:

- from value to `Task` or
- from `Either` to `Task`

But yes, it does seem to be simpler than monad transformers especially in respect to the fact monads are hardly composable - in order to define monad transformer you have to know some other details about your type besides being a monad (usually it requires something like comonad to extract value).

Just for advertising purposes, I would also add that `Task` represents stack-safe trampolined computation.

However, there are some projects focused on extended monadic composition, like Emm-monad: https://github.com/djspiewak/emm, so you can compose monad transformers with `Future`/`Task`, `Either`, `Option`, `List` and so on and so forth. But, IMO, it's still limited in comparison with `Applicative` composition - `cats` provides universal `Nested` data type that allows to easily compose any Applicative, you can find some examples [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542127/1809978) - the only disadvantage here is that it's hard to build a readable DSL using Applicative. Another alternative is so-called "Freer monad": https://github.com/m50d/paperdoll, which basically provides better composition and allows to separate different effect layers into different interpreters.

For example, as there is no `FutureT`/`TaskT` transformer you can't build effects like `type E = Option |: Task |: Base` (`Option` from `Task`) as such `flatMap` would require extraction of value from the `Future`/`Task`.

As a conclusion, I can say that from my experience `Task` really comes in hand for do-notation based DSLs: I had a complex external rule-like DSL for async computations and when I decided to migrate it all to Scala-embedded version `Task` really helped - I literally converted external-DSL to Scala's `for-comprehension`. Another thing we considered is having some custom type, like `ComputationRule` with a set of type classes defined over it along with conversions to `Task`/`Future` or whatever we need, but this was because we didn't use `Free`-monad explicitly.

---

You might even not need `Free`-monad here assuming you don't need an ability to switch interpreters (which might be true for *just* system tests). In that case `Task` might be the only thing you need - it's lazy (in comparison with Future), truly functional and stack-safe:

```
 trait DSL {
   def put[E](e: E): Task[Unit]
   def count[E](e: E): Task[Int]
 }

 object Implementation1 extends DSL {

   ...implementation
 }

 object Implementation2 extends DSL {

   ...implementation
 }


//System-test script:

def test0(dsl: DSL) = {
  import dsl._
  for {
    _ <- put("Apple")
    _ <- put("Orange")
    _ <- put("Pinneaple")
    nApples <- count("Apple")
    nPears <- count("Pear")
    nBananas <- count("Banana")
  } yield List(("Apple", nApples), ("Pears", nPears), ("Bananas", nBananas))
 }
```

So you can switch implementation by passing different "interpreter" here:

```
test0(Implementation1).unsafeRun
test0(Implementation2).unsafeRun
```

Differences/Disadvantages (in comparison with http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html):

- you stuck with `Task` type, so you can't collapse it to some other monad easily.
- implementation is resolved in runtime  when you pass an instance of DSL-trait (instead of natural transformation), you can easily abstract it using eta-expansion: `test0 _`. Polymorphic methods (put, count) are naturally supported by Java/Scala, but poly functions aren't so it's easier to pass instance of `DSL` containing  `T => Task[Unit]` (for `put` operation) than making synthetic polymorphic function `DSLEntry[T] => Task[Unit]` using natural-transform `DSLEntry ~> Task`.
- no explicit AST as instead of pattern matching inside natural transformation - we use static dispatch (explicitly calling a method, which will return lazy computation) inside DSL trait

Actually, you can even get rid of `Task` here:

```
 trait DSL[F[_]] {
   def put[E](e: E): F[Unit]
   def count[E](e: E): F[Int]
 }

 def test0[M[_]: Monad](dsl: DSL[M]) = {...}
```

So here it might even become a matter of preference especially when you're not writing an open-source library.

Putting it all together:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

trait DSL[F[_]] {
   def put[E](e: E): F[Unit]
   def count[E](e: E): F[Int]
 }

def test0[M[_]: Monad](dsl: DSL[M]) = {
    import dsl._
    for {
      _ <- put("Apple")
      _ <- put("Orange")
      _ <- put("Pinneaple")
      nApples <- count("Apple")
      nPears <- count("Pear")
      nBananas <- count("Banana")
    } yield List(("Apple", nApples), ("Pears", nPears), ("Bananas", nBananas))
 }

object IdDsl extends DSL[Id] {
   def put[E](e: E) = ()
   def count[E](e: E) = 5
}
```

Note that cats have a `Monad` defined for `Id`, so:

```
scala> test0(IdDsl)
res2: cats.Id[List[(String, Int)]] = List((Apple,5), (Pears,5), (Bananas,5))
```

simply works. Of course, you can choose `Task`/`Future`/`Option` or any combination if you prefer. As a matter of fact, you can use `Applicative` instead of `Monad`:

```
def test0[F[_]: Applicative](dsl: DSL[F]) = 
  dsl.count("Apple") |@| dsl.count("Pinapple apple pen") map {_ + _ }

scala> test0(IdDsl)
res8: cats.Id[Int] = 10
```

`|@|` is a parallel operator, so you can use `cats.Validated` instead of `Xor`, be aware that `|@|` for Task isn't executed (at least in older scalaz version) in parallel (parallel operator not equals parallel computation). You can also use a combination of both:

```
import cats.syntax._

def test0[M[_]:Monad](d: DSL[M]) = {
    for {
      _ <- d.put("Apple")
      _ <- d.put("Orange")
      _ <- d.put("Pinneaple")
      sum <- d.count("Apple") |@| d.count("Pear") |@| d.count("Banana") map {_ + _ + _}
    } yield sum
 }

scala> test0(IdDsl)
res18: cats.Id[Int] = 15
```